# Billing account for project is not open GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I'm trying to launch a compute instance into GCP using the command line:

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=uscentral1-a
```

And it tells me that billing is not open for the project:

```
API [compute.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [847006780503].
Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)?
(y/N)?  Y

Enabling service [compute.googleapis.com] on project [847006780503]...
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Billing account for project '847006780503' is not open. Billing must be enabled for activation of service(s) 'compute.googleapis.com,compute.googleapis.com,compute.googleapis.com' to proceed.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - subject: ?error_code=390002&project=847006780503&services=compute.googleapis.com&services=compute.googleapis.com&services=compute.googleapis.com
    type: googleapis.com/billing-enabled
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com/billing-enabled
  metadata:
    project: '847006780503'
    services: compute.googleapis.com,compute.googleapis.com,compute.googleapis.com
  reason: UREQ_PROJECT_BILLING_NOT_OPEN
```

I am able to launch compute instances in the console, but not on the CLI.

How do I enable billing for my project so that I can launch instances with the CLI?

Comment: If you try to create the instance through the Google cloud console, the error message includes a link to the right page to enable billing. Enabling billing is a one-time action, so your command line will work from then on for all instances belonging to that project.

Comment: I just found out that I can create an instance through the google cloud console. It's just not working on the CLI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### To confirm that billing is enabled on your  project please follow the next steps:

1. Sign in to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/?_ga=2.166018878.1678639349.1608561231-549298192.1605204650&_gac=1.95592814.1607379213.CjwKCAiAwrf-BRA9EiwAUWwKXs96xT84WhL0QBiVkLmROl1-j7OMiZgF9_fG3wrg7DyO4b74YpHFjRoCjlcQAvD_BwE).
2. In the project drop down ( My Project) at the top of the Google Cloud Console page, select your project.
3. Open the console Navigation menu , and then select Billing.

**If billing is not enabled on the project**, a pop-up window will display, with text similar to:

```
"This project is not linked to a billing account"
```

If this is your case, you can enable billing on your project following this documentation: [Enable billing for an existing project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_an_existing_project)

#### To re-enable billing on a project, do the following.

1. [Sign in to the Manage billing accounts page](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing) in the Google Cloud Console.
2. Select the **My projects** tab to view a list of projects and the associated Cloud Billing account for each project.
3. From the list of projects, locate the project for which you want to re-enable billing, and then click the menu next to it.
4. Select **Change billing**, then choose the desired destination Cloud Billing account.

Comment: Can it also be done through gcloud CLI somehow?